# DISTINCT to only one column

Tags: sql, distinct

I'm using a query and attempting to modify it so that it only returns distinct "lodnum" where there is over 2 entries of said "lodnum".

I've looked into ROW_NUMBER() OVER / PARTITIONS. I just cannot seem to get it to do what I want.

The query is: (Sorry about formatting)

```
SELECT i.lodnum,
      i.prtnum,
      i.lotnum,
      sum(i.untqty),
      i.ftpcod,
      i.invsts
      FROM inventory_view i,
               locmst m
      WHERE i.stoloc = m.stoloc
      AND m.arecod = 'PART-HSY'
      AND i.prtnum NOT IN (SELECT i2.prtnum
                                       FROM inventory_view i2,
                                                locmst m2
                                       WHERE i2.stoloc = m2.stoloc
                                       AND m2.arecod = 'PART-HSY'
                                       AND i2.lotnum = i.lotnum
                                       AND i2.invsts = i.invsts
                                       GROUP BY i2.prtnum
                                       HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
      AND i.lodnum IN (SELECT i3.lodnum FROM inventory_view i3, locmst m3
                                       WHERE i3.stoloc = m3.stoloc
                                       AND m3.arecod = 'PART-HSY'
                                       AND i3.lotnum = i.lotnum
                                       AND i3.invsts = i.invsts
                                       GROUP BY i3.lodnum
                                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

GROUP BY 
     i.lodnum,
    i.stoloc,
    i.prtnum,
    i.lotnum,
    i.ftpcod,
    i.invsts
ORDER BY 
    i.prtnum,
    i.lotnum,
    i.invsts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look like:

```
with t as (
      YOUR QUERY HERE WITHOUT ORDER BY
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by lodnum order by lodnum) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by prtnum, lotnum, invsts;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, got side tracked with some tasks and forgot to respond. Thanks a lot for your help. That worked as-is with my query pasted into the area you defined. +1!